# CGAL Surface Reconstruction from Point Sets

Tags: c++, mesh, triangulation, cgal

I have a point set obtained via kinect, now I want to create a mesh. I'm trying to use CGAL libraries and I'm following [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/index.html#title7).

I'm using VS2010, it runs without any error, but of course it doesn't find the file "kittem.xyz" requested in the line:

```
std::ifstream stream("data/kitten.xyz");
if (!stream ||
    !CGAL::read_xyz_points_and_normals(
                          stream,
                          std::back_inserter(points),
                          CGAL::make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(PointList::value_type())))
{
  std::cerr << "Error: cannot read file data/kitten.xyz" << std::endl;
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

1) *.xyz is a file extension?

2) how i should store data in this file?

3) where can i find the file kitten.xyz?

Answer (score 3):

`xyz` is a very simple format which contains 6 floating point numbers per line. The first three are the coordinates of the point, the next three are the corresponding normal. Storing data in those files is trivial.

You can find `kitten.xyz` if you [download CGAL](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=52&release_id=8576) and check the `examples/Surface_reconstruction_3/data/` folder.

Comment: thanks! in order to better understand this example, I have to work with "poisson_reconstruction.cpp" or "poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp"?

Comment: @user3516105 `poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp` illustrates the use of the API quite well.

Comment: ok, thanks! now i have another problem, I made another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495529/cgal-surface-reconstruction-from-point-sets-2